# Data acquisition optimization

Tags: python, django, database, html-table

There are a lot of records in the table (450k records), how can I get them faster than in this way?

```
def index(request):
params = Parameters.objects.all()
return render(request, "core/data_table.html", {"params": params})
```

I bring in the table on html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
   <html>
<body>
{% if params.count > 0 %}
    <h2>Data</h2>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Id</th><th>par_time</th><th>par_recipe</th><th>par_machine</th><th>par_fa</th><th>par_ag_typ</th><th>par_rollennr</th>
        <th>par_def_id</th><th>par_name</th><th>par_value</th></tr>
        {% for person in params %}
        <tr><td>{{ params.id }}</td><td>{{ params.par_time }}</td><td>{{ params.par_recipe }}</td><td>{{ params.par_machine }}</td>
        <td>{{ params.par_fa }}</td><td>{{ params.par_ag_typ }}</td><td>{{ params.par_rollennr }}</td><td>{{ params.par_def_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ params.par_name }}</td><td>{{ params.par_value }}</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
<p><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Return to home</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you really need to work with 450k table rows in a browser?

Comment: I concur with Bruce, I find it hard to believe you would need to display 450k records. Even if you could absorb 450k records of information as a human, if you were to inspect them at 1 second a record it would take you over 5 full days of reading to get to the bottom. I would only display the first X records and then add pagination or some sort of grouping per letter. Another option is a search function or some sort of filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- The first solution is to pass just the values that you want back to template. 
based on what i see in your code, you are using `id, par_time, ..., par_value`, So just pass this values to template not all python objects. like this:

```
 Parameters.objects.all().values('id', 'par_time', ....
```

this method is more optimized than just passing python objects.

2- Use pagination in your django template. You don't need to load all data in table (User side). Paginate all your data and pass for example each 10 items per page. There are rich documents for how to use pagination in django. Here is a [list of pagination apps](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/pagination/) to use in your django project.